# How to fadeIn new results to jQuery AJAX autoupdating div

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, twitter

I have a div that is populated with an external php file, that loops results from a MySQL query. I would like the div to refresh every 5 seconds using AJAX, and have only the new results fade in at the top of the list, while the others just move down, like Twitter and Facebook.

I am new to AJAX, and this is what I have now in the head of my document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#load_tweets').load('inc/searchresults.php');
});
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('inc/searchresults.php').fadeIn(5000);
}, 5000); // refresh every 5 seconds
</script>
```

Right now, the content does not load on document ready, but all of the div does refresh every 5 seconds, however it does not fade in. I have three questions, first, how can I fix my code so that the div loads on page load? Second, how can I get it to fade in properly?

Finally, how would I go about only fading in the new results? I'm thinking it would involve fading in items with a primary key > the ones from the previous AJAX call, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're calling the `fadeIn` function asynchronously, it's running at the same time as the load and not having time to complete before it gets called again. Also, you're never fading out. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        function update_div()
        {
            $('#load_tweets').fadeOut('normal', function()
            {
                $('#load_tweets').load('inc/searchresults.php');
                $('#load_tweets').fadeIn(5000, function()
                {
                    window.setTimeout("update_div()", 5000);
                });
            });
        }

        update_div();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to not load all the content again, simply insert the new content above hidden and then add fade it in.

```
// Untested, written here without syntax.
var timeSinceUpdate = <?php echo(time()); ?>; //Needs to be system time so that it works correctly
$(document).ready(function(){    
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('inc/queriesSince.php?searched=something+something&timesinceupdate=' + timeSinceUpdate , function(data){
            alert(data);
            if(confirm('Add new Data to screen?'))
            {
                //Add Stuff to DOM and 
                //update the timeSinceUpdate from the data recieved so that it is system time.
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```